# Is there a simple way to quickly pass the entire contents of a given array into an `Array.prototype` method variable without using parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, prototype, splice

**context**

I created an array `docket` to keep track of coordinates as the user clicks on a canvas space. During the main program loop the array is to be scanned by a draw function so that selected pixels can be seen. Originally, inside of my event listener, I was using the `push(  )` method but then I realized I wanted a way to sort of toggle the pixels.

**code description**

So I added a method `poke(  )` to `Array.prototype`, as seen below, which allows me to push the whole `docket` array into a local array `param.array` and assign the trigger coordinate to a local variable `param.entry`. `entry` is then pushed into `array` and `array` is processed by the main `poke(  )` loop to ensure there are no duplicate values. If a match is found, both elements are annihilated and `param.array` is returned to the top, ultimately shrinking `docket` by 1; If no matches are found then no elements are annihilated and `param.array` is returned to the top, ultimately expanding `docket` by 1.

**main issue: example 1**

Anyway, as the method is currently written, it must be called thusly:

`docket.poke( docket, e.key );` *Note: for simplicity I have used keyboard key values.*

```
Array.prototype.poke = function( a, b ) {
  var bool = {  },  i = {  },  param = {  };
  param.array = a;  param.entry = b;    
  //
  param.array.push( param.entry );
  i.len = param.array.length;
  i.end = i.len - 1;
  //
  for ( i.cur = 0; i.cur < i.len; i.cur++ ) {
    bool.match = param.array[ i.cur ] == param.array[ i.end ];
    bool.nSelf = !( i.cur == i.end );
    //
    if ( bool.match && bool.nSelf ) {
      param.array.splice( i.end, 1 );
      param.array.splice( i.cur, 1 );
      //
      i.end -= 2;
      i.len -= 2;
    }
  }
  //
  return param.array;
}
```

This seems a little redundant, but it offers two critical advantages. First to readability and aesthetic. Being able to visibly pass off the contents of `docket` to a local array for processing and then visibly return the results to the top I think is very helpful to comprehension. Second, both this example and the next use a sort of confusing truth test to filter out false positives on duplicate value detection. This example doesn't have too though. It could easily be rewritten to compare each element in `param.array` to `param.entry` using a tight, no nonsense for loop.

**main issue: example 2**

`docket.poke( e.key );` is the less redundant and more desired approach. This is my code.

```
Array.prototype.poke = function( a ) {
  var bool = {  },  entry = a,  i = {  };
  //
  this.push( entry );
  i.len = this.length;
  i.end = i.len - 1;
  //
  for ( i.cur = 0; i.cur < i.len; i.cur++ ) {
    bool.match = this[ i.cur ] == this[ i.end ];
    bool.nSelf = !( i.cur == i.end );
    //
    if ( bool.match && bool.nSelf ) {
      this.splice( i.end, 1 );
      this.splice( i.cur, 1 );
      //
      i.end -= 2;
      i.len -= 2;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, this eliminates the the redundancy in the call, but it sacrifices some readability of the method and more importantly the opportunity to really slim up the code using the simple comparison I mentioned above.

So now I'm wondering if there is some less than obvious way that I've missed which will allow me to pass the full contents of my array to a local variable without having to first pass them in as a parameter of its own method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why all those local objects? Do you have something against primitives?

Comment: I think it helps me stay organized. I cite the bool object as an example. I mean when you check out the for loop condition area, to see the word bool attached to the variable it makes it much easier to see what's going on in my mind. I'm learning though and my practices are constantly shifting.

Comment: "access the contents of my array without having to pass them in as a parameter of its own method" -- it sounds like `this` is *exactly* what you've just described. It's not clear to me why you think it "reduces readability". `this` means "the object used when calling this function as a method" so in terms of readability, that's exactly what you want to do, and exactly what `this` is meant to express in this context. I also second the idea that using `i` and `bool` variables to needlessly "namespace" your local vars is quite confusing and harms the readability of your code.

Comment: @apsillers I take your advice regarding name spacing, and have reworded the section of my question you quoted to more accurately describe my intention.

Comment: Regarding your edit to "pass the full contents of my array to a local variable": perhaps `somelocalVar = this;` ...? Or, if you only want a copy of the array, `someLocalVar = this.splice();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to define the method on the prototype if you are going to pass the array as an argument. A plain function would be just fine for that.

The second version of your code has indeed the advantage that you can apply the method to a given array instead of passing the array to a function.

The code could however be simplified if:

- You would only add the element *after*  you have determined it does not yet occur in the array
- You would use `indexOf`:

```js
Array.prototype.toggle = function(value) {
    var index = this.indexOf(value);
    if (index > -1) {
        this.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        this.push(value);
    }
}

var a = [4,2,5,8];
a.toggle(2);
console.log(a.join());
a.toggle(2);
console.log(a.join());
```

NB: I personally find the name `toggle` more telling than `poke`.

Consider also the power of a `Set`: it will find an existing member in constant time (while an array implementation needs linear time), and will also be able to remove it in constant time. So if you are open to using something else than an array for this, go for a `Set`.

```js
Set.prototype.toggle = function(value) {
    if (!this.delete(value)) this.add(value);
}

var a = new Set([4,2,5,8]);
a.toggle(2);
console.log([...a].join());
a.toggle(2);
console.log([...a].join());
```

Comment: This looks great. I'll try some of this when I get off work and let you know how it turned out.

Comment: Haven't tested `Set` yet. You say the routine would take the same amount time no matter how large the set is? Neat! Anyway, I went with `indexOf(  )` as suggested by you, as well as imported the array with `this` like apsillers suggested (though I was sure I'd tried that). Here's my new code. `Array.prototype.poke = function( a ) {
 var array = this, value = a;
 var bool = {  }, i = {  };
 i.match = array.indexOf( value );
 bool.match = i.match >= 0;

  if ( bool.match ) {
  array.splice( i.match, 1);
  return array;
 }
 else {
  array.push( value );
  return array;
 }
}`.Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed a Set provides constant-time `has`, `get` and `set` methods. NB: Why not call the parameter `value` immediately instead of assigning `a` to `value`? Also, `return array;` does not have to occur twice, just put it after the `if ... else` block.

Comment: I've been doing that with parameters since day one. Looking back I think it was my original attempt at name spacing --although now that you've called my attention to it I think I no longer need to do it that way. The double return statement was a distracted oversight. Thanks again for everything.